# Old password not being accepted when attempting to change password

Tags: macos, password, user-account

I was trying to change my password from System Preferences on my MacBook Pro. I followed the procedure by filling in the old password along with the new one. However, I am informed that the old password is incorrect! I tried several times but it didn't succeed. The old password is not working so the newer one is not being set.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please add your OS version, and add details as where exactly are you trying to change your password on System Preferences. Thanks!

Comment: did you set it up so that you can use the Apple ID to recover ?

Comment: is cap lock on? did you change the keyboard layout ?

Answer (score 1):

You can reboot into recovery and run `resetpassword` from Terminal to reset your password.